# Google map ignores touch events from overlay widgets

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I've created a `Stack` widget containing `HomePage` and `GoogleMapView` widgets.

```dart
 return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[GoogleMapView(),  HomePage()],
    );
```

`HomePage` is just a simple `Scaffold` widget contains a bottom navigation bar and a transparent background.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      bottomNavigationBar:
          BottomNavigationBar(type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, items: [...]),
    );
```

But, I can not scroll the map. In Android, we removed `clickable=true` from layouts to make map scrollable.

However, I wrapped my home page with `IgnorePointer` class but it disables all touch events from all visible widgets (e.g. bottom navigation bar will not accept any click events).

Comment: Use `GoogleMapView()` as `body:` of your `Scaffold()`.

Comment: @RubensMelo, Yes but it makes my code complicated. Because I have multiple screens (with their own routing) and every screen has its own `Scaffold` (e.g. one screen need appbar, another one needs bottom navigation, etc)